# Graphite carbon-relay not working

Tags: monitoring, metrics, graphite

I have two graphite setup and I am trying to relay the traffic between the two, but somehow the carbon-relay is not working.
My cache runs on 2003/2004 and relay on 2013/2014
Following are the configurations done :

```
#carbon file


[cache:b]
LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2003
PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2004
CACHE_QUERY_PORT = 7012



[relay]
LINE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2013
PICKLE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2014
RELAY_METHOD = rules

REPLICATION_FACTOR = 1

 DESTINATIONS = 127.0.0.1:2003:a, aa.bb.cc.dd:2003:b


#relay-rules file

[default]
default = true
destinations = 127.0.0.1:2003:a, aa.bb.cc.dd:2003:b

Any pointers will be helpful
```

Answer (score 8):

As part of the recent project at work, I've figured out that carbon demons uses PICKLE protocol when sending data to the destinations.

So the destination of carbon-relay should be carbon-cache's pickle receiver port instead.

```
#carbon.conf
....

[relay]
LINE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
LINE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2013
PICKLE_RECEIVER_INTERFACE = 0.0.0.0
PICKLE_RECEIVER_PORT = 2014
RELAY_METHOD = rules

REPLICATION_FACTOR = 1

DESTINATIONS = 127.0.0.1:2004:a, aa.bb.cc.dd:2004:b
```

---

Also modify the relay-rules.conf with the same destinations specified in carbon.conf
    relay-rules.conf
    .....

```
[default]
default = true 
destinations = 127.0.0.1:2004:a, aa.bb.cc.dd:2004:b
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing that out, I was getting "invalid line received" from carbon-aggregator and couldn't find out why. Then I realized the the protocols may be different, but couldn't find any documentation about this.